# Science fiction story revolving around telepathy

Tags: story-identification, telepathy, telekinesis

Trying to find a book I read in the late 70's or very early 80's.

As I remember, the plot centered around a rock star who transferred his consciousness to a computer, and whom "made contact" with a Russian telepath. The telepath was, iirc, actually a "living brain" - or slices of - held in some form of life-sustaining container. One of them may have been based on a satellite, and may have had telekinetic powers.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *[Star Fire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/687730.Star_Fire)* by Ingo Swann.

Rock star Dan Merriweather develops paranormal powers, and discovers both the US and Russians possess installations using human psychic powers as weapons. To evade them he fakes his own death.

The Russian Project Tolkien involves slices of human brain installed in satellites

Comment: Huh. Good catch. I'd run into that one in my search, but had found no mention of the satellites.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is it. It's available on Amazon for a penny, so I've splurged on the postage and should have it in a week or two.

Many thanks!

Comment: And it is. Book arrived promptly, with a cover picture that jogged the mind. Haven't had a chance to do more than skim as my partner promptly picked it up and started reading it!  Many thanks, all!